# Mongo / Ruby driver output specific number of documents at a time?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Ruby Mongo Driver question:

How do I output 5_000 document batches from the collection at a time until I read the last document in the collection without dumping the entire database into memory first?

*This is really bad method for me*:

```
mongo = MongoClient.new('localhost', 27017)['sampledb']['samplecoll']
@whois.find.to_a....
```

Comment: If I can understand you don't want to load entire bunch of records? Use `limit` and `skip` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo::Collection#find returns a Mongo::Cursor that is Enumerable.  For batch processing Enumerable#each_slice is your friend and well worth adding to your toolkit.

Hope that you like this.

find_each_slice_test.rb

```
require 'mongo'
require 'test/unit'

class FindEachSliceTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @samplecoll = Mongo::MongoClient.new('localhost', 27017)['sampledb']['samplecoll']
    @samplecoll.remove
  end

  def test_find_each_slice
    12345.times{|i| @samplecoll.insert( { i: i } ) }
    slice__max_size = 5000
    @samplecoll.find.each_slice(slice__max_size) do |slice|
      puts "slice.size: #{slice.size}"
      assert(slice__max_size >= slice.size)
    end
  end
end
```

ruby find_each_slice_test.rb

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

slice.size: 5000
slice.size: 5000
slice.size: 2345
.

Finished tests in 6.979301s, 0.1433 tests/s, 0.4298 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```